# How did Finral transport Yami into the cave?

Tags: black-clover

It is said that Finral can only use his spatial magic to open portals to places that he has already been. Is there some kind of exception to this?

In episode 34, Finral opens a portal to a cave where Asta is fighting members of a certain organization. This allows Yami to assist Asta, but it seems very strange that he would have been into this random cave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the corresponding manga chapter #47, where Yami mentions that Noelle contacted HQ about the situation and they were dispatched because they were the ones closest to that town.

I think the teleportation in this case was short-ranged, done in order to block Licht's attack and save Asta. So they must have already entered the cave for it to be in Finral's line of sight.

It is indeed unlikely that Finral would have visited the cave before, but it seems plausible that Finral might have visited the town before, since it is near to their base. So they could have teleported to the town and then made their way to the cave on foot.

Comment: This seems completely plausible.